# Why is EEPROM commit not registering int values?

Tags: esp8266, eeprom, esp8266webserver

```
       if(jsonDoc["delayOn"].as<int>() <= 255 && jsonDoc["delayOff"].as<int>() <= 255 && jsonDoc["delayUnitOn"].as<int>() <= 2 && jsonDoc["delayUnitOff"].as<int>() <= 2 && 
         jsonDoc["mode"].as<int>() <= 1 && jsonDoc["blink"].as<int>() <= 1 && 
         jsonDoc["timeOnHour"].as<int>() <= 23 && jsonDoc["timeOnMinute"].as<int>() <= 59 && 
         jsonDoc["timeOffHour"].as<int>() <= 23 && jsonDoc["timeOffMinute"].as<int>() <= 59) {

        int val;
        int addr_init = (relay*eepromSlotsPerRelayPin)*sizeof(int);
        
        val = jsonDoc["blink"].as<int>();
        EEPROM.put(addr_init,val);
        if(jsonDoc["blink"].as<int>()==1){ //0=off,1=on        

          val = jsonDoc["mode"].as<int>();
          EEPROM.put(addr_init+(5*sizeof(int)),val);
          
          
          if (jsonDoc["mode"].as<int>()==0){ //blink mode

            val = jsonDoc["delayOn"].as<int>();
            EEPROM.put(addr_init+(1*sizeof(int)),val);
            val = jsonDoc["delayOff"].as<int>();
            EEPROM.put(addr_init+(3*sizeof(int)),val);
            //1=minute,0=second,2=hour
            val = jsonDoc["delayUnitOn"].as<int>();
            EEPROM.put(addr_init+(2*sizeof(int)),val);
            val = jsonDoc["delayUnitOff"].as<int>();
            EEPROM.put(addr_init+(4*sizeof(int)),val);
            EEPROM.end();
                            
          }else if(jsonDoc["mode"].as<int>()==1){ //time switch mode

            val = jsonDoc["timeOnHour"].as<int>();
            EEPROM.put(addr_init+(6*sizeof(int)),val);
            val = jsonDoc["timeOnMinute"].as<int>();
            EEPROM.put(addr_init+(7*sizeof(int)),val);
            val = jsonDoc["timeOffHour"].as<int>();
            EEPROM.put(addr_init+(8*sizeof(int)),val);
            val = jsonDoc["timeOffMinute"].as<int>();
            EEPROM.put(addr_init+(9*sizeof(int)),val);
            EEPROM.end();
          }
          else {
            request->send(412, "text/plain", "unknown mode");
            return;
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        request->send(412, "text/plain", "a parameter is not within limits");            
        return;
      }        
      
      //initBlinkPinObjs
      int addr_init;
      int val,uom;
      for(int i = 0; i<maxRelayPins; i++) {
        bPinObjs[i].pin = relayPins[i];
        //EEPROM Slot per Relay dataStruct
        //0=>enable, 1=>durationOn, 2=>durationOnTimeMeasure,  
        //3=>durationOff, 4=>durationOffTimeMeasure
        //5=>mode, 6=>timeOnHour, 7=>timeOnMinute, 
        //8=>timeOffHour, 9=>timeOffMinute

        addr_init = (i*eepromSlotsPerRelayPin)*sizeof(int);
        
        val = 0;
        EEPROM.get(addr_init,val);
       bPinObjs[i].enable = val;

        val = 0;
        EEPROM.get(addr_init+(5*sizeof(int)),val);
        bPinObjs[i].mode = val;

        val = 0;
        EEPROM.get(addr_init+(6*sizeof(int)),val);
        bPinObjs[i].timeOnHour=val;

        val = 0;
        EEPROM.get(addr_init+(7*sizeof(int)),val);
        bPinObjs[i].timeOnMinute=val;

        val = 0;
        EEPROM.get(addr_init+(8*sizeof(int)),val);
        bPinObjs[i].timeOffHour = val;

        val = 0;
        EEPROM.get(addr_init+(9*sizeof(int)),val);
        bPinObjs[i].timeOffMinute = val;
        
        //delayOn
        //convert to millisec            
        uom = 0;
        EEPROM.get(addr_init+(2*sizeof(int)),uom);
        switch(uom){
          case 0:
            bPinObjs[i].durationOn=0;
            val = 0;
            EEPROM.get(addr_init+(1*sizeof(int)),val);
            bPinObjs[i].durationOn = val*1000;
          break;
          case 1:
            bPinObjs[i].durationOn=0;
            val = 0;
            EEPROM.get(addr_init+(1*sizeof(int)),val);
            bPinObjs[i].durationOn = val*60000;
          break;
          case 2:
            bPinObjs[i].durationOn=0;
            val = 0;
            EEPROM.get(addr_init+(1*sizeof(int)),val);
            bPinObjs[i].durationOn = val*3600000;
          break;
          default:
          break;
        }       
        //delayOff
        //convert to millisec
        uom = 0;
        EEPROM.get(addr_init+(4*sizeof(int)),uom);
        switch(uom){
          case 0:
            bPinObjs[i].durationOff = 0;
            val = 0;
            EEPROM.get(addr_init+(3*sizeof(int)),val);
            bPinObjs[i].durationOff = val*1000;
          break;
          case 1:
            bPinObjs[i].durationOff = 0;
            val = 0;
            EEPROM.get(addr_init+(3*sizeof(int)),val);
            bPinObjs[i].durationOff = val*60000;
          break;
          case 2:
            bPinObjs[i].durationOff = 0;
            val = 0;
            EEPROM.get(addr_init+(3*sizeof(int)),val);
            bPinObjs[i].durationOff = val*3600000;
          break;
          default:
          break;
        }    
      }
```

```
--JSON INPUT printed from server--

relay:0
blink:1
mode:1
delayOn:56
delayOff:2
delayUnitOn:0
delayUnitOff:0
timeOnHour:5
timeOnMinute:56
timeOffHour:7
timeOffMinute:48
```

```
OUTPUT printed from server:
--Objects content--
Size of INT:4
---------0--------- init addr: 0
[0]enable: 0
[1]durationOn: 0
[2]durationOnUom: 0
[3]durationOff: 0
[4]durationOffUom: 0
[5]mode: 0
[6]onHr: 0
[7]onMin: 0
[8]offHr: 0
[9]offMin: 0
---------1--------- init addr: 40
[0]enable: 0
[1]durationOn: 0
[2]durationOnUom: 0
[3]durationOff: 0
[4]durationOffUom: 0
[5]mode: 0
[6]onHr: 0
[7]onMin: 0
[8]offHr: 0
[9]offMin: 0
---------2--------- init addr: 80
[0]enable: 0
[1]durationOn: 0
[2]durationOnUom: 0
[3]durationOff: 0
[4]durationOffUom: 0
[5]mode: 0
[6]onHr: 0
[7]onMin: 0
[8]offHr: 0
[9]offMin: 0
---------3--------- init addr: 120
[0]enable: 0
[1]durationOn: 0
[2]durationOnUom: 0
[3]durationOff: 0
[4]durationOffUom: 0
[5]mode: 0
[6]onHr: 0
[7]onMin: 0
[8]offHr: 0
[9]offMin: 0
---------4--------- init addr: 160
[0]enable: 0
[1]durationOn: 0
[2]durationOnUom: 0
[3]durationOff: 0
[4]durationOffUom: 0
[5]mode: 0
[6]onHr: 0
[7]onMin: 0
[8]offHr: 0
[9]offMin: 0
---------5--------- init addr: 200
[0]enable: 0
[1]durationOn: 0
[2]durationOnUom: 0
[3]durationOff: 0
[4]durationOffUom: 0
[5]mode: 0
[6]onHr: 0
[7]onMin: 0
[8]offHr: 0
[9]offMin: 0
---------6--------- init addr: 240
[0]enable: 0
[1]durationOn: 0
[2]durationOnUom: 0
[3]durationOff: 0
[4]durationOffUom: 0
[5]mode: 0
[6]onHr: 0
[7]onMin: 0
[8]offHr: 0
[9]offMin: 0
---------7--------- init addr: 280
[0]enable: 0
[1]durationOn: 0
[2]durationOnUom: 0
[3]durationOff: 0
[4]durationOffUom: 0
[5]mode: 0
[6]onHr: 0
[7]onMin: 0
[8]offHr: 0
[9]offMin: 0
---------8--------- init addr: 320
[0]enable: 0
[1]durationOn: 0
[2]durationOnUom: 0
[3]durationOff: 0
[4]durationOffUom: 0
[5]mode: 0
[6]onHr: 0
[7]onMin: 0
[8]offHr: 0
[9]offMin: 0
```

This is inside an esp8266 async webserver `server.on` method.
My `EEPROM.begin` is in `setup` function.
Initially, only the first `put` within a block becomes committed .
Now, nothing is registering after I implemented the `sizeof(int)` inside addresses.

The intention is to store `int` data passed thru `http post` per relay pin [total of 9 pins]. The program then uses the data to perform on a relay:

- blink
- switch on/off based on time (hour,minute)
  ...

I've tried all sorts to fix:

- `commit`,`end` after every `put`
- `EEPROM.begin(512)` then `commit` & `end` on every `put`
- add `delay`s
- use `end` only instead of `commit`
- add address range for `sizeof(int)`

Comment: try the arduino example code

Comment: how do you know that commit applies to only the first put?

Comment: I print it in Serial. I did try the `write` & `read` from sample but it does not meet my requirement to store `int`.

Comment: `(relay*eepromSlotsPerRelayPin)+(relayDataIndex * sizeOf(int))` will try this out as the address values based on @VictorTiamson and @RollyAvecilla suggestions.

Comment: edit: `((relay*eepromSlotsPerRelayPin)*sizeof(int))+(relayDataIndex * sizeof(int))`

Comment: New challenge, now nothing is registering. Edited the code displayed in post with my updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, i commented out the `val=0;` before `EEPROM.get`s also replaced `EEPROM.end` with `EEPROM.commit`.

This is the output now:

```
--Objects content--
Size of INT:4
---------0--------- init addr: 0
[0]enable: 1
[4]durationOn: 3000
[8]durationOnUom: 0
[12]durationOff: 2000
[16]durationOffUom: 0
[20]mode: 1
[24]onHr: 9
[28]onMin: 11
[32]offHr: 9
[36]offMin: 12
---------1--------- init addr: 40
[40]enable: 1
[44]durationOn: 0
[48]durationOnUom: -1
[52]durationOff: 0
[56]durationOffUom: -1
[60]mode: -1
[64]onHr: -1
[68]onMin: -1
[72]offHr: -1
[76]offMin: -1
---------2--------- init addr: 80
[80]enable: 1
[84]durationOn: 0
[88]durationOnUom: -1
[92]durationOff: 0
[96]durationOffUom: -1
[100]mode: -1
[104]onHr: -1
[108]onMin: -1
[112]offHr: -1
[116]offMin: -1
---------3--------- init addr: 120
[120]enable: 1
[124]durationOn: 0
[128]durationOnUom: -1
[132]durationOff: 0
[136]durationOffUom: -1
[140]mode: 1
[144]onHr: 5
[148]onMin: 56
[152]offHr: 7
[156]offMin: 48
---------4--------- init addr: 160
[160]enable: 1
[164]durationOn: 0
[168]durationOnUom: -1
[172]durationOff: 0
[176]durationOffUom: -1
[180]mode: -1
[184]onHr: -1
[188]onMin: -1
[192]offHr: -1
[196]offMin: -1
---------5--------- init addr: 200
[200]enable: 1
[204]durationOn: 0
[208]durationOnUom: -1
[212]durationOff: 0
[216]durationOffUom: -1
[220]mode: -1
[224]onHr: -1
[228]onMin: -1
[232]offHr: -1
[236]offMin: -1
---------6--------- init addr: 240
[240]enable: 1
[244]durationOn: 0
[248]durationOnUom: -1
[252]durationOff: 0
[256]durationOffUom: -1
[260]mode: -1
[264]onHr: -1
[268]onMin: -1
[272]offHr: -1
[276]offMin: -1
---------7--------- init addr: 280
[280]enable: 1
[284]durationOn: 0
[288]durationOnUom: -1
[292]durationOff: 0
[296]durationOffUom: -1
[300]mode: -1
[304]onHr: -1
[308]onMin: -1
[312]offHr: -1
[316]offMin: -1
---------8--------- init addr: 320
[320]enable: 1
[324]durationOn: 0
[328]durationOnUom: -1
[332]durationOff: 0
[336]durationOffUom: -1
[340]mode: -1
[344]onHr: -1
[348]onMin: -1
[352]offHr: -1
[356]offMin: -1


--JSON inputs--

relay:0
blink:1
mode:1
delayOn:3
delayOff:2
delayUnitOn:0
delayUnitOff:0
timeOnHour:9
timeOnMinute:11
timeOffHour:9
timeOffMinute:12
```